# javascript onfocus/onblur specific to input - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this form in html:

```
<form id="ConSupAp" name="ConSupAp" action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Name of the Applicant's Organisation:
<input type="text" id="input_1_1" name="input_1_1" placeholder="Name of the Applicant's Organisation" value="Default value here" required>

Contact Person:
<input type="text" id="input_1_2" name="input_1_2" placeholder="Contact Person" value="Default person here" required>

Telephone (Landline):
<input type="text" id="input_1_3" name="input_1_3" placeholder="Telephone (Landline)" value="0123456789" required>

Telephone (Mobile):
<input type="text" id="input_1_4" name="input_1_4" placeholder="Telephone (Mobile)" value="01782242565" required></td>

Email:
<input type="text" id="input_1_5" name="input_1_5" placeholder="Email" value="demo@example.com" required>

Fax:
<input type="text" id="input_1_6" name="input_1_6" placeholder="Fax" value="" required>

Address:
<textarea id="input_1_7" name="input_1_7" placeholder="Address" required></textarea>

</form>
```

There are a total of 24 fields to the complete form but that is not important so I won't list more at this time. I have this at the END of the page:

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("ConSupAp");
x.addEventListener("focus", myFocusFunction, true);
x.addEventListener("blur", myBlurFunction, true);

function myFocusFunction() {
document.getElementById("input_1_1").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
document.getElementById("input_1_2").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function myBlurFunction() {
document.getElementById("input_1_1").style.backgroundColor = "";
document.getElementById("input_1_2").style.backgroundColor = "";
}
</script>
```

However this seems to make both the first and second inputs respectively yellow and red when ANY input is focussed, and does not operate on a per field situation - which is obviously what I want if I am to have a different or simialar/same action for each field.

So how do I make the functionality operate specifically for one targeted input field, and if focus changed from input_1_1 to input_1_2 then the onfocus function works on 1_2 while the onblur works on 1_1 ??

Note - jQuery IS being used on this page.

Update - I have created this version to try to highlight what I am wanting. I don't actually want colour background changes at all. I am **trying** to make this the starting point for some onblur AJAX but I have had problems trying to ask the question as a whole, here on SO. People seem to be a little unappreciative of the bigger picture and my initial request for help was marked as "too broad". I am trying to break it down (painfully) into small pieces. First being go get a js trigger to work when a field is onblur and the user moves to the next field. I don't want this looped in specific order. I **just** want a trigger to happen to each specific input field when the onblur event occurs on it so I can then figure out how to throw it to the server, and display a result based on the server side php spitting something back.

Answer (score 0):

The form is in focus whenever any of it's child input elements are in focus - which is what is happening when you are clicking on them.

Do you want the highlights for the first two fields only?
Attach event listeners to the respective input elements instead of the form as a whole for "per field basis" effects.

If you want something different, then you have to change the script accordingly.

Edit: If you want a behaviour where the input has to be done in the order the fields are present and as you move down, the inputs already done should be made "red" and the current one "yellow", then here is a fiddle:

[Serial Form I/O](http://jsfiddle.net/5b4c42zh/3/)

Carefully notice how the event listeners are assigned in the loop and how the user is forced to enter data in a serial order.

```
var input_elements = document.getElementsByClassName("form_ip");
```

Add the same class name for all the input elements i.e. `"form_ip"` and select them as a list. Then add all the event listeners with a `done` array which stores whether user has entered a value in the previous input element or not.

```
for (var i = 0; i < done.length; ++i) {
    // Closures save the day, to avoid variable hoisting otherwise.
    (function (i) {
        input_elements[i].addEventListener("focus", function () {
            for (var j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
                // If a previous input element is blank, move to that instead
                if (!done[j]) {
                    input_elements[j].focus();
                    return;
                }
                handleBlur(j);
            }
            handleFocus(i);

            // we are done with ith element if it has a value
            done[i] = input_elements[i].value.length > 0;
        }, false);
    }(i));
}
```

The `handleBlur` and `handleFocus` functions are defined in the script.

**Re-edit**
In that case, just assign an event listener to each input element's `onblur` event and store the values somewhere. You can also check for input validity in the listener and let the user know about it. When you want to sent it via AJAX, just assimilate the data into an object, convert the said object to JSON and send it. On the server side, parse the JSON data and extract the values.

Comment: are you able to either point me towards a demo (for dummies) or throw me some example code? I think what you have said in your re-edit might be exactly what I am in need of. Thank you!

Comment: Here is a modified fiddle. Search for "your AJAX code goes here!!!" in the function `send`. The script converts the form data into JSON and shows in a div below the form. Also, you wont need action attribute in your form in case you are using AJAX for communication. 
http://jsfiddle.net/5b4c42zh/8/

Answer (score 0):

First of all the JavaScript code belong in the header and not in the bottom of the page. Also don't write code like `var x = document.getElementById("ConSupAp");` just like that. Put it into the `onLoad` method. ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload))

As Akash said, if you attach the event listener to the form it will work on the form. What you want is attaching them to the textfields. If you are using jQuery you can use CSS selectors to do that in a loop instead of listing the fields, but thats your choice.

For a test just try something like:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var x;
    x = document.getElementById("input_1_1");
    x.addEventListener("focus", myBlurFunction1_1, true);
    x.addEventListener("blur", myBlurFunction1_1, true);

    x = document.getElementById("input_1_2");
    x.addEventListener("focus", myBlurFunction1_2, true);
    x.addEventListener("blur", myBlurFunction1_2, true);

    x = document.getElementById("input_1_3");
    x.addEventListener("focus", myBlurFunction1_3, true);
    x.addEventListener("blur", myBlurFunction1_3, true);
    ...

    // Don't reference the "ConSupAp" at all.
}
```

### Edit

Use this kind of callback for modularity:

```
function myBlurFunction1_1() {
    document.getElementById("input_1_1").style.backgroundColor = "";
}
function myBlurFunction1_2() {
    document.getElementById("input_1_2").style.backgroundColor = "";
}
function myBlurFunction1_3() {
    document.getElementById("input_1_3").style.backgroundColor = "";
}
```

Comment: It does not work when placed in the header. The howto I used to get this far clearly stated to place it AFTER the html. At the end of getting it to work (please read my update in the main question) I plan to have it load from a .js file referenced within the head section, as long as I can get it to work by doing so. I don't want it in the html document at all.

Comment: I kinda understand the example given, but where is it O define what exactly is supposed to happen - ie the myFocusFunction and myBlurFunction ?

Comment: Well my answer actually was binding the callbacks to the textfields, the note about where to put your code was just a friendly suggestion from my experience.

Comment: Define them at the same place that works. Just instead of binding to the form, bind them to the textfields themselves.

Comment: I'm not very good with js at all. I barely use it aside form the most basic of things, so please bear with me. What I have used in the starting example is what I have learned or seen as an example in online how-to's, so if it is bad/wrong I don't mind changing it at all. As long as we improve stuff and not start to play back and forwards with methodologies. I don't really have the time to undo/redo things 20 times till I get the actual objective finished. :)

Comment: Can you give me an example? And will this work if loaded from the head within an external .js file?

Comment: I edited my answer because I noticed that something was missing. See it now, it should be clear. There is of course a way to do it with less copy-paste, but that is a bit more headache for JS newbies.

Comment: Did you read my update in the main question? I am actually needing this to be the start position for an AJAX function to talk to some php on the server. Perhaps it'll help to tidy this part if that is clear. Next I need to figure out how to serialize it, and perform the functionality for all kinds of fields etc.

Comment: You should maybe open a new question on AJAX. This question has been answered. Also try to read up on the subject.

Comment: Sorry the answer has not been clearly understood, so I cannot mark this as answered. I have already opened a query on AJAX with the result I have already stated, which has lead me to breaking it painfully down into pieces.